# Using QProcess for CLI

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess, qtcore, pscp

How can I use QProcess for Command Line Interactive arguments, I am trying to a transfer a file usimg scp which prompts for password

```
QString program = "c:/temp/pscp.exe";
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "C:/Users/polaris8/Desktop/Test1GB.zip" <<   "Mrigendra@192.168.26.142:/home/";
QPointer<QProcess> myProcess;
myProcess = new QProcess;
connect(myProcess, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(readOutput()));
myProcess->start(program , arguments);
```

After this the commnad Line asks for Password how to satisfy it using QProcess , can I overcome it by giving some options in my arguments only for scp, or what should be the code in my slot readOutput that throws the password to Command Line . Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: pass username/password as arguments to scp

Comment: @LaszloPapp right. so he needs to pick another program to copy

Comment: I wouldn't mess with passwords but use key-based authentication instead.

Comment: @BЈовић: ah, hmm. pscp is an sftp client, too, and that indeed has username and password options unlike scp.

Comment: @LaszloPapp...I am using bash a bit of detail would be helpful....thanks

Comment: @user3110438: already posted an answer a while ago. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can pass the username / password as options with:

```
-l user
-pw passwd
```

So your arguments should look like this:

```
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "-l" << "Mrigendra" << "-pw" << "Password" <<
             "C:/Users/polaris8/Desktop/Test1GB.zip" <<
             "192.168.26.142:/home/";
```

Comment: Fwiw, the QProcess documentation prefers the `QStringList arguments;
    arguments << "-style" << "fusion";` style. I think, in the Qt world, "-pw Password" are two arguments rather than one. At least terminology and logically, but your code may work.

Comment: @ThorKhan , Thanks but its not working with QProcess but works well in Windows Command Prompt....

Comment: @user3110438: for the reason, I mentioned. You would need to split "-pw password" into separate arguments as per my answer.

Comment: Strictly speaking, there is still some room for improvement since there is no such a type as `StringList`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that scp does not have such options, but pscp (sftp client does have). So, I would be writing something like this to extend your initial arguments with that option based on the [following man page](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.53b/htmldoc/Chapter5.html#5):

```
QString program = "c:/temp/pscp.exe";
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "-pw" << "password" << "C:/Users/polaris8/Desktop/Test1GB.zip" << "Mrigendra@192.168.26.142:/home/";
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
QPointer<QProcess> myProcess;
myProcess = new QProcess;
connect(myProcess, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(readOutput()));
myProcess->start(program , arguments);
```

Also, I would encourage you to use [QStandardPaths](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html#StandardLocation-enum) for a path like yours. See the documentation for details:

```
QStandardPaths::DesktopLocation 0   Returns the user's desktop directory.
```

So, you could eventually replace this string:

```
"C:/Users/polaris8/Desktop/Test1GB.zip"
```

with the following:

```
QStandardPaths::locate(QStandardPaths::DesktopLocation, "Test1GB.zip")
```

That being said, you may wish to consider using keys instead of password in the future. It would be a bit more secure, and also convenient for your application.

Comment: ordering matters,as the order you stated prompts for password and even QProcess fails..arguments << "C:/Users/polaris8/Desktop/Test1GB.zip" << "-pw" << "password" << "Mrigendra@192.168.26.142:/home/"; works fine in windows command Line but Qproces fails .....Am I making Qt unhappy any where in this statement

Comment: Correct order is arguments << "-pw" << "polaris" << "C:/Users/polaris8/Desktop/ToDo.txt" << "Mrigendra@192.168.26.142:/home/";...It works Thanks Laszlo and @ThorKhan

Comment: @user3110438: Also, as per my answer and hint about QStandardPaths, please do not use hard coded paths in your code.

Comment: will keep a look on QStandardPaths..Thanks for pointing it out...Laszlo is there a way to get rid of username and passwords and just use keys using pscp ?

Comment: @user3110438: http://dafis.ucdavis.edu/install/sftp/PuttyPSCPKey.cfm Does that help?